# How to prove that the Schur algebra is isomorphic to a certain endomorphism ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

I'm reading Green's book
''Polynomial Representations of GL_n. with an Appendix on Schensted Correspondence and Littelmann Paths''.

Consider theorem 2.6c) on page 18:

Let $K$ be an infinite field and $G(r):=\Sigma_r$, the symmetric group on $r$ elements. Let $E:=K^n$.

Let $\psi:S_K(n,r)\rightarrow \text{End}_K(E^{\otimes r})$ be the representation afforded by the
$S_K(n,r)$-module $E^{\otimes r}$. Then

(i) $\text{Im}(\psi)= \text{End}_{KG(r)}({E}^{\otimes r})$, and
(ii) $\text{Ker}(\psi) = 0$.

Hence, $S_K(n,r)\cong \text{End}_{KG(r)}({E}^{\otimes r})$.

> I don't know, how to prove that the map
>   $\psi: S_K(n,r)\rightarrow \text{End}_{KG(r)}(E^{\otimes r})$
>   is an algebra homomorphism.
>
> $K$-linearity is clear, but why is $\psi$ multiplicative?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should reproduce the theorem for those of us who don't have the book :P

Comment: What is $S_K(n,r)$?

Comment: $S_K(n,r):={A_K(n,r)}^{*}=\text{Hom}_K(A_K(n,r),K)$ and $A:=A_K(n):=\text{polynomial functions on}\ \Gamma:=\text{GL}_n(K)$ and

$A_K(n,r):=\text{the subspace of}\ A\ \text{consisting of the elements expressible as polynomials}
\ 
\text{homogeneous of degree}\ r$.

Comment: The map $\psi$ is multiplicative because it is a representation.  A representation of an algebra is by definition an algebra homomorphism, so in particular multiplicative.